# Javascript - memory issues when dealing with large arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-leaks

I'm working on a Javascript app which does a lot of per-pixel operations on arrays which represent image data. When I'm setting up the arrays, I start with an empty '[]' and then fill it up with zeros, a bit like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <script>
      function makeBigArray()
      {
        // Create a data array for a 5000*5000 RGB image
        var imageData = [];
        for (var i = 0, lenI = 5000*5000*3; i < lenI; i++)
        {
            imageData.push(0);
        }
      }
    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <button onclick="makeBigArray()">Make Big Array</button>

  </body>

</html>
```

I noticed quite quickly that a loop like this causes what seems to be a massive memory hit. When I execute the above code, I get memory usages in the 2GB range.

Can someone explain why simply pushing elements into an array like that creates such high memory usage?

Comment: The array will scale dynamically as you put stuff in it. When it reaches a big enough size, it would need more memory allocated, so you'd get a whole new chunk of memory allocated, then the contents copied, then the old array would need to be garbage collected.

Comment: 75 million numbers is about 600 megabytes, and system memory is allocated in chunks that get bigger as the desired (requested) storage space gets bigger.

Comment: Use a typed array for dealing with pixel "byte" data.

Comment: It's easy to imagine what you are doing is similar to creating an RGB image, which would be about 24MB. That's what I thought when looked at this. What you are doing is different, however. Each pixel in an RGB image is 8-bits, but you are making an array of javascript numbers, which are significantly larger.

Comment: Just use typed arrays, you don't need that many bytes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays . Uint8 arrays are perfect for your scenario.

Comment: Well, you are trying to allocate 75k numbers. Each number is 8 bytes. That makes is a lot more than 24MB. Besides, the array cannot know how many items you'll put there - it would grow proportionately. I don't know if arrays are optimised for so many items in them, either, so they could grow really large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, every number is a `double`, and on most systems is 8 bytes. That means your array is 600000000 bytes on most systems (600 MB). As well, most times when you push to your array, the browser allocates a new block of memory, and the garbage collector doesn't free the memory immediatly. If memory is a problem, use the Array constructor with one number, for the amount of elements, to perform less allocations. You could also use typed arrays, but they are CPU-intensive to modify.

Comment: "*on most systems is 8 bytes*" - JS numbers are *always* 64 bits (8 bytes)

Comment: "*every time you push to your array, the browser allocates a new block of memory*" - no, that would be very inefficient. Resizable arrays are allocated using more clever strategies.

Comment: @Bergi Fixed as I realized std::vector allocates more memory than it needs.

Comment: `If memory is a problem, use the Array constructor with one number, for the amount of elements, to perform only one allocation` that would not allocate memory for all the members, though. Think about it - *how* would that even work? You can make an array for 100 items but they could be booleans or integers, or strings, or custom objects, or even mixed. You can also have sparse arrays. How much memory would you allocate for `new Array(100)`?

Comment: 5000 squared is 25,000,000 (25 million). Times 3 that's 75 million, and times 8 (size of a double) that's **600MB**, not 60.